# How can nfs service in the kernel be disabled?

Tags: kernel

How can nfs service in the kernel be disabled?

As far as I can see there are no userland utils

```
# find / -name nfs* -print
/sys/kernel/slab/nfs_page
/sys/kernel/slab/nfs_inode_cache
/sys/kernel/slab/nfs_read_data
/sys/kernel/slab/nfs_write_data
/sys/kernel/slab/nfs_direct_cache
/sys/module/nfs
/sys/module/nfs/parameters/nfs4_disable_idmapping
/var/lib/pacman/sync/core/nfsidmap-0.23-3
/var/lib/pacman/sync/core/nfs-utils-1.2.2-3
/usr/include/rpcsvc/nfs_prot.x
/usr/include/rpcsvc/nfs_prot.h
/usr/include/nfs
/usr/include/nfs/nfs.h
/usr/include/linux/nfsd
/usr/include/linux/nfsd/nfsfh.h
/usr/include/linux/nfs2.h
/usr/include/linux/nfs.h
/usr/include/linux/nfs4.h
/usr/include/linux/nfsacl.h
/usr/include/linux/nfs3.h
/usr/include/linux/nfs_mount.h
/usr/include/linux/nfs_fs.h
/usr/include/linux/nfs4_mount.h
/usr/include/linux/nfs_idmap.h
/usr/share/man/man2/nfsservctl.2.gz
/proc/sys/fs/nfs
/proc/sys/fs/nfs/nfs_callback_tcpport
/proc/sys/fs/nfs/nfs_mountpoint_timeout
/proc/sys/fs/nfs/nfs_congestion_kb
/proc/sys/sunrpc/nfs_debug
/proc/sys/sunrpc/nfsd_debug
/proc/fs/nfs
/proc/fs/nfsfs
/proc/fs/nfsd
/proc/1/net/rpc/nfsd.fh
/proc/1/net/rpc/nfsd.export
/proc/1/net/rpc/nfsd
/proc/1/net/rpc/nfs
/proc/2/net/rpc/nfsd.fh
/proc/2/net/rpc/nfsd.export
/proc/2/net/rpc/nfsd
/proc/2/net/rpc/nfs
/proc/3/net/rpc/nfsd.fh
/proc/3/net/rpc/nfsd.export
/proc/3/net/rpc/nfsd
/proc/3/net/rpc/nfs
/proc/4/net/rpc/nfsd.fh
/proc/4/net/rpc/nfsd.export
/proc/4/net/rpc/nfsd
/proc/4/net/rpc/nfs
/proc/5/net/rpc/nfsd.fh
/proc/5/net/rpc/nfsd.export
/proc/5/net/rpc/nfsd
/proc/5/net/rpc/nfs
/proc/6/net/rpc/nfsd.fh
/proc/6/net/rpc/nfsd.export
/proc/6/net/rpc/nfsd
/proc/6/net/rpc/nfs
/proc/7/net/rpc/nfsd.fh
/proc/7/net/rpc/nfsd.export
/proc/7/net/rpc/nfsd
/proc/7/net/rpc/nfs
/proc/8/net/rpc/nfsd.fh
/proc/8/net/rpc/nfsd.export
/proc/8/net/rpc/nfsd
/proc/8/net/rpc/nfs
/proc/9/net/rpc/nfsd.fh
/proc/9/net/rpc/nfsd.export
/proc/9/net/rpc/nfsd
/proc/9/net/rpc/nfs
/proc/10/net/rpc/nfsd.fh
/proc/10/net/rpc/nfsd.export
/proc/10/net/rpc/nfsd
/proc/10/net/rpc/nfs
/proc/11/net/rpc/nfsd.fh
/proc/11/net/rpc/nfsd.export
/proc/11/net/rpc/nfsd
/proc/11/net/rpc/nfs
/proc/12/net/rpc/nfsd.fh
/proc/12/net/rpc/nfsd.export
/proc/12/net/rpc/nfsd
/proc/12/net/rpc/nfs
/proc/13/net/rpc/nfsd.fh
/proc/13/net/rpc/nfsd.export
/proc/13/net/rpc/nfsd
/proc/13/net/rpc/nfs
/proc/14/net/rpc/nfsd.fh
/proc/14/net/rpc/nfsd.export
/proc/14/net/rpc/nfsd
/proc/14/net/rpc/nfs
/proc/15/net/rpc/nfsd.fh
/proc/15/net/rpc/nfsd.export
/proc/15/net/rpc/nfsd
/proc/15/net/rpc/nfs
/proc/16/net/rpc/nfsd.fh
/proc/16/net/rpc/nfsd.export
/proc/16/net/rpc/nfsd
/proc/16/net/rpc/nfs
/proc/17/net/rpc/nfsd.fh
/proc/17/net/rpc/nfsd.export
/proc/17/net/rpc/nfsd
/proc/17/net/rpc/nfs
/proc/20/net/rpc/nfsd.fh
/proc/20/net/rpc/nfsd.export
/proc/20/net/rpc/nfsd
/proc/20/net/rpc/nfs
/proc/23/net/rpc/nfsd.fh
/proc/23/net/rpc/nfsd.export
/proc/23/net/rpc/nfsd
/proc/23/net/rpc/nfs
/proc/24/net/rpc/nfsd.fh
/proc/24/net/rpc/nfsd.export
/proc/24/net/rpc/nfsd
/proc/24/net/rpc/nfs
/proc/220/net/rpc/nfsd.fh
/proc/220/net/rpc/nfsd.export
/proc/220/net/rpc/nfsd
/proc/220/net/rpc/nfs
/proc/222/net/rpc/nfsd.fh
/proc/222/net/rpc/nfsd.export
/proc/222/net/rpc/nfsd
/proc/222/net/rpc/nfs
/proc/224/net/rpc/nfsd.fh
/proc/224/net/rpc/nfsd.export
/proc/224/net/rpc/nfsd
/proc/224/net/rpc/nfs
/proc/234/net/rpc/nfsd.fh
/proc/234/net/rpc/nfsd.export
/proc/234/net/rpc/nfsd
/proc/234/net/rpc/nfs
/proc/238/net/rpc/nfsd.fh
/proc/238/net/rpc/nfsd.export
/proc/238/net/rpc/nfsd
/proc/238/net/rpc/nfs
/proc/248/net/rpc/nfsd.fh
/proc/248/net/rpc/nfsd.export
/proc/248/net/rpc/nfsd
/proc/248/net/rpc/nfs
/proc/257/net/rpc/nfsd.fh
/proc/257/net/rpc/nfsd.export
/proc/257/net/rpc/nfsd
/proc/257/net/rpc/nfs
/proc/258/net/rpc/nfsd.fh
/proc/258/net/rpc/nfsd.export
/proc/258/net/rpc/nfsd
/proc/258/net/rpc/nfs
/proc/343/net/rpc/nfsd.fh
/proc/343/net/rpc/nfsd.export
/proc/343/net/rpc/nfsd
/proc/343/net/rpc/nfs
/proc/344/net/rpc/nfsd.fh
/proc/344/net/rpc/nfsd.export
/proc/344/net/rpc/nfsd
/proc/344/net/rpc/nfs
/proc/387/net/rpc/nfsd.fh
/proc/387/net/rpc/nfsd.export
/proc/387/net/rpc/nfsd
/proc/387/net/rpc/nfs
/proc/456/net/rpc/nfsd.fh
/proc/456/net/rpc/nfsd.export
/proc/456/net/rpc/nfsd
/proc/456/net/rpc/nfs
/proc/485/net/rpc/nfsd.fh
/proc/485/net/rpc/nfsd.export
/proc/485/net/rpc/nfsd
/proc/485/net/rpc/nfs
/proc/487/net/rpc/nfsd.fh
/proc/487/net/rpc/nfsd.export
/proc/487/net/rpc/nfsd
/proc/487/net/rpc/nfs
/proc/499/net/rpc/nfsd.fh
/proc/499/net/rpc/nfsd.export
/proc/499/net/rpc/nfsd
/proc/499/net/rpc/nfs
/proc/500/net/rpc/nfsd.fh
/proc/500/net/rpc/nfsd.export
/proc/500/net/rpc/nfsd
/proc/500/net/rpc/nfs
/proc/501/net/rpc/nfsd.fh
/proc/501/net/rpc/nfsd.export
/proc/501/net/rpc/nfsd
/proc/501/net/rpc/nfs
/proc/502/net/rpc/nfsd.fh
/proc/502/net/rpc/nfsd.export
/proc/502/net/rpc/nfsd
/proc/502/net/rpc/nfs
/proc/503/net/rpc/nfsd.fh
/proc/503/net/rpc/nfsd.export
/proc/503/net/rpc/nfsd
/proc/503/net/rpc/nfs
/proc/504/net/rpc/nfsd.fh
/proc/504/net/rpc/nfsd.export
/proc/504/net/rpc/nfsd
/proc/504/net/rpc/nfs
/proc/513/net/rpc/nfsd.fh
/proc/513/net/rpc/nfsd.export
/proc/513/net/rpc/nfsd
/proc/513/net/rpc/nfs
/proc/514/net/rpc/nfsd.fh
/proc/514/net/rpc/nfsd.export
/proc/514/net/rpc/nfsd
/proc/514/net/rpc/nfs
/proc/515/net/rpc/nfsd.fh
/proc/515/net/rpc/nfsd.export
/proc/515/net/rpc/nfsd
/proc/515/net/rpc/nfs
/proc/516/net/rpc/nfsd.fh
/proc/516/net/rpc/nfsd.export
/proc/516/net/rpc/nfsd
/proc/516/net/rpc/nfs
/proc/517/net/rpc/nfsd.fh
/proc/517/net/rpc/nfsd.export
/proc/517/net/rpc/nfsd
/proc/517/net/rpc/nfs
/proc/518/net/rpc/nfsd.fh
/proc/518/net/rpc/nfsd.export
/proc/518/net/rpc/nfsd
/proc/518/net/rpc/nfs
/proc/523/net/rpc/nfsd.fh
/proc/523/net/rpc/nfsd.export
/proc/523/net/rpc/nfsd
/proc/523/net/rpc/nfs
/proc/525/net/rpc/nfsd.fh
/proc/525/net/rpc/nfsd.export
/proc/525/net/rpc/nfsd
/proc/525/net/rpc/nfs
/proc/1056/net/rpc/nfsd.fh
/proc/1056/net/rpc/nfsd.export
/proc/1056/net/rpc/nfsd
/proc/1056/net/rpc/nfs
/proc/1145/net/rpc/nfsd.fh
/proc/1145/net/rpc/nfsd.export
/proc/1145/net/rpc/nfsd
/proc/1145/net/rpc/nfs
/proc/1188/net/rpc/nfsd.fh
/proc/1188/net/rpc/nfsd.export
/proc/1188/net/rpc/nfsd
/proc/1188/net/rpc/nfs
/proc/1191/net/rpc/nfsd.fh
/proc/1191/net/rpc/nfsd.export
/proc/1191/net/rpc/nfsd
/proc/1191/net/rpc/nfs
/proc/1219/net/rpc/nfsd.fh
/proc/1219/net/rpc/nfsd.export
/proc/1219/net/rpc/nfsd
/proc/1219/net/rpc/nfs
/proc/1284/net/rpc/nfsd.fh
/proc/1284/net/rpc/nfsd.export
/proc/1284/net/rpc/nfsd
/proc/1284/net/rpc/nfs
/proc/1289/net/rpc/nfsd.fh
/proc/1289/net/rpc/nfsd.export
/proc/1289/net/rpc/nfsd
/proc/1289/net/rpc/nfs
/proc/1379/net/rpc/nfsd.fh
/proc/1379/net/rpc/nfsd.export
/proc/1379/net/rpc/nfsd
/proc/1379/net/rpc/nfs
/proc/1380/net/rpc/nfsd.fh
/proc/1380/net/rpc/nfsd.export
/proc/1380/net/rpc/nfsd
/proc/1380/net/rpc/nfs
/proc/1412/net/rpc/nfsd.fh
/proc/1412/net/rpc/nfsd.export
/proc/1412/net/rpc/nfsd
/proc/1412/net/rpc/nfs
/proc/1421/net/rpc/nfsd.fh
/proc/1421/net/rpc/nfsd.export
/proc/1421/net/rpc/nfsd
/proc/1421/net/rpc/nfs
/proc/1432/net/rpc/nfsd.fh
/proc/1432/net/rpc/nfsd.export
/proc/1432/net/rpc/nfsd
/proc/1432/net/rpc/nfs
/proc/1444/net/rpc/nfsd.fh
/proc/1444/net/rpc/nfsd.export
/proc/1444/net/rpc/nfsd
/proc/1444/net/rpc/nfs
/proc/1445/net/rpc/nfsd.fh
/proc/1445/net/rpc/nfsd.export
/proc/1445/net/rpc/nfsd
/proc/1445/net/rpc/nfs
/proc/1446/net/rpc/nfsd.fh
/proc/1446/net/rpc/nfsd.export
/proc/1446/net/rpc/nfsd
/proc/1446/net/rpc/nfs
/proc/1448/net/rpc/nfsd.fh
/proc/1448/net/rpc/nfsd.export
/proc/1448/net/rpc/nfsd
/proc/1448/net/rpc/nfs
/proc/1473/net/rpc/nfsd.fh
/proc/1473/net/rpc/nfsd.export
/proc/1473/net/rpc/nfsd
/proc/1473/net/rpc/nfs
/proc/1499/net/rpc/nfsd.fh
/proc/1499/net/rpc/nfsd.export
/proc/1499/net/rpc/nfsd
/proc/1499/net/rpc/nfs
```

Comment: Your search for filesystem entries only find those beginning with nfs. Try searching using <code>*nfs*</code> on my system that finds things like /sbin/mount.nfs and similar things.

Comment: You might want to mention the operating system or linux distribution ...

Answer (score 1):

You could compile a kernel without nfs support and reboot using that kernel.

I would suggest that you just

```
rmmod nfs
rmmod nfsd
```

and any other nfs related modules (e.g. exportfs, lockd, sunrpc) but from the find output it does not look like nfs is compiled in as modules in your kernel.

Comment: Also, remove the relevant Sxx and Kxx scripts from the rc.d/init.d directories.